# Show ID on Crud Screen with Spring Roo

Tags: java, spring-roo

I want to show the Id as well on CRUD Screens with Spring Roo.

New to Spring Roo,Wanted to know is it possible or not.

```
    package com.roopoc.domain;
    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Version;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

    import 
            org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.annotations.RooEquals;
    import 
           org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.annotations.RooJavaBean;
    import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.annotations.RooToString;
    import org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.annotations.entity.RooJpaEntity;

    /**
     * = TeacherDetails
     TODO Auto-generated class documentation
     *
     */
    @RooJavaBean
    @RooToString
    @RooJpaEntity(table = "TEACHER_DETAILS")
    @RooEquals(isJpaEntity = true)
    public class TeacherDetails implements Serializable {


        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "SCHOOL_CODE")
        private Long schoolCode;


        /**
         * TODO Auto-generated attribute documentation
         *
         */
        @Version
        private Integer version;

        /**
         * TODO Auto-generated attribute documentation
         *
         */
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "TEACHER_NAME")
        private String teacherName;

    }
```

Want to show Id,schoolCode,teacherName in Crud Screens,I am only Getting schoolCode,teacherName.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you send info about Spring Roo version, Java versión, O.S., etc.?

Comment: Spring Roo 2.0.0,Java 1.8,OS windows.